# Year, volume, journal, order biblatex

Tags: biblatex

First of all, sorry for the maybe noobish question, but I am getting into LaTeX again, and feel rather new, and currently I am struggling with getting my bibliography to be as I want to. Currently I just use:

`\usepackage[style=phys, backend=bibtex, sorting=none, maxbibnames=3, minbibnames=3, biblabel=brackets]{biblatex}`,

and the result is:

[image]

I would really like it to look more like this:

[image]

Hence, a period after the names. Title not in quotes. Period after title. Name of the journal followed by year;volume:pages.

IS this easy achievable, or does it need a lot of tweaking?

Comment: You can patch the style using package `xpatch`, which has dedicated patching commands (`\xpatchbibmacro, \xpatchbibdriver`, &c.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks pretty much like the style produced by [`biblatex-nejm`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-nejm).

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=nejm, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\autocite{sigfridsson,aksin}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Sigfridsson E and Ryde U. Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments. Journal of Computational Chemistry 1998;19:377–95.//Aksın Ö, Türkmen H, Artok L et al. Effect of immobilization on catalytic characteristics of saturated Pd-N-heterocyclic carbenes in Mizoroki-Heck reactions. J. Organomet. Chem. 2006;691:3027–36.]